# Installation of `brew install llvm` leads to "Segmentation fault: 11" on macOS

Tags: llvm, homebrew

For some program [LDSTORE](http://www.christianbenner.com/#) I need to install `llvm` on my Mac (macOS 10.13). I do this using `brew install llvm`. This leads to a `Segmentation fault: 11` message when running `ldstore`, or other (C++ based?) programs. 
How can I fix this?

It clearly has to do with `llvm`, as doing `brew uninstall llvm` fixes the issue (obvious `ldstore` won't work in that case).
For what it's worth: I use the native python 2.7.10.

As per suggestion of [Stanislav Pankevich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/598057/stanislav-pankevich) I ran `lldb ldstore_v11` followed by `r`, resulting in this:

```
lldb ldstore_v11
(lldb) target create "ldstore_v11"
Current executable set to 'ldstore_v11' (x86_64).
(lldb) r
Process 15841 launched: '/Users/swvanderlaan/bin/ldstore_v11' (x86_64)
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libiomp/lib/libiomp5.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/swvanderlaan/bin/ldstore_v11
  Reason: image not found
Process 15841 stopped
* thread #1, stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x0000000100095216 dyld`__abort_with_payload + 10
dyld`__abort_with_payload:
->  0x100095216 <+10>: jae    0x100095220               ; <+20>
    0x100095218 <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x10009521b <+15>: jmp    0x100094a74               ; cerror_nocancel
    0x100095220 <+20>: retq
Target 0: (ldstore_v11) stopped.
```

It's odd that the library is **not** found, as I clearly added to my bash_profile the following line: `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"`, as per suggestion of the installation messages.

Hope someone can help me debug this.

Thanks,

Sander
*P.S. I hope it's clear, I'm not trying to develop anything, I'm just trying to use LDSTORE.*

Comment: Start by doing `lldb your-program` and then pressing `r`. LLDB should give you more information about the crash.

Comment: Another thing I would recommend is to not use `brew install` but rather get LLVM binaries from http://releases.llvm.org/download.html. For example I have these binaries for multiple versions of LLVM located in `/opt/llvm-3.9`, `/opt/llvm-4.0`, etc respectively. This way you don't make LLVM to interfere with Mac OS's stuff. This is how I as a developer work with LLVM.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this tool is dynamically linked against libiomp5.dylib, which must be present at `/usr/local/opt/libiomp/lib/libiomp5.dylib` for it to work.

As suggested by Stanislav, download the precompiled binaries from http://releases.llvm.org/5.0.0/clang+llvm-5.0.0-x86_64-apple-darwin.tar.xz. This contains the library you need: `./lib/libiomp5.dylib`. You'll have to copy the library into `/usr/local/opt/libiomp/lib`, which probably won't exist yet.

Once you've done that, you'll be able to run `ldstore`.

Comment: Yes, this is what I've discovered and what I did. It's a bit illogical to me that `ldstore` points to something in such a way that is not guaranteed to work. But anyway: it works now!